# In VS Code, how to change the background color for matching HTML tag?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to customize how my theme highlights a paired HTML tag. I find that the default highlight is not sufficiently visible to see the opening or closing tag easily.

I'm looking for something analogous to this setting for bracket matching:
`"workbench.colorCustomizations": { "editorBracketMatch.background" },`

This only changes the background for matching brackets, I want to do the same for opening and closing HTML tags (see screenshot).

[Background of matching HTML tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA2tp.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76813932/836330

Answer (score -1):

You can use this VSCode extension to colorize matching pair of brackets:
[Bracket Pair Colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer)

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I can already change the background color of brackets without using an extension.