VS Code html tag color
anyone can tell me what class/tag/whatever is creating this reddish highlight when html tag is selected? all plugins are disabled and no custom theme is used. thanks


duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49784220/11107541

Highlighting matching tags is a built-in vs code feature.
Take a look at this SO question.
I believe that this is the setting you are looking for
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": "off".
Happy coding!

actually setting  "editor.linkedEditing": false, as someone suggested and then deleted it worked for me. thanks for the help

Cool, glad you figured it out :)
